# How to get the lowest value without knowing the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, reduce

```
const a = [
  {
    id: 2343,
    status: {
      prepped: 1,
      draft: 1,
      active: 2,
      maintenance: 6,
      on_rent: 8,
      unprepped: 10
    }
  },
  {
    id: 45,
    status: {
      prepped: 1,
      draft: 1,
      active: 2,
      unprepped: 10
    }
  }
];
```

Given the array of objects (above). How to get the key with the lowest value in status?. Because I want to compare if status.active <= status.(this is the key with the lowest value).
Note: Dont iclude the key(prepped and draft).

```
if(status.active <= status.(this is the key with the lowest value)){
   return true
}
```

Comment: do you want lowest value for active key ?

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh, I want to get the key with the lowest value (except for draft and prepped) in each object in an array and compare it to the value of active.

Comment: `Object.entries` will help - that will result in an array like `[[key, value],[key,value]]` - you can  then filter out the keys you want to ignore, then use whatever method you prefer to get the lowest value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, the result for both of those objects in your example array would be true, since active IS less than all the values (other than the excluded ones)

So, I added another object where that isn't the case for testing - so the result should be true, true and false?

```js
const a = [{
        id: 2343,
        status: {
            prepped: 1,
            draft: 1,
            active: 2,
            maintenance: 6,
            on_rent: 8,
            unprepped: 10
        }
    }, {
        id: 45,
        status: {
            prepped: 1,
            draft: 1,
            active: 2,
            unprepped: 10
        }
    },
    {
        id: 46,
        status: {
            prepped: 1,
            draft: 1,
            active: 2,
            unprepped: 1
        }
    }
];
const ignored = ['prepped', 'draft', 'active'];

const fn1 = o => {
    const {active} = o;
    const min = Math.min(...Object.entries(o).filter(([key]) => !ignored.includes(key)).map(([,value]) => value));
    return active <= min;
}
a.forEach(o => {
  console.log(o.id, fn1(o.status));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something purely logical. You can use this, something i did quickly.

```
const a = [
  {
    id: 2343,
    status: {
      prepped: 1,
      draft: 1,
      active: 2,
      maintenance: 6,
      on_rent: 8,
      unprepped: 10
    }
  },
  {
    id: 45,
    status: {
      prepped: 1,
      draft: 1,
      active: 2,
      unprepped: 10
    }
  }
]

let largestVal = 0
a.forEach((obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj.status).forEach((statusKey) => {
    if (obj.status[statusKey] > largestVal) {
      largestVal = obj.status[statusKey]
    }
  })
})

console.log(largestVal)
```